# Two OS in same computer, how to set boot priority for windows 7?

Tags: windows, linux, centos, boot, centos-5

I have Centos and Win 7 installed in same PC. How Can I change setting in CentOS to show Windows 7 in top of the list in boot menu ?

Answer (score 3):

Edit your `/boot/grub/grub.conf` (or `/boot/grub/menu.lst`) so that the entry that looks like

```
title Windows 7
    ....
    ....
```

is the topmost of the entries (they all start with `title`)

You need to either log in as root (`su`) or use sudo, e.g. `sudo <your favourite editor> /etc/boot/menu.lst`

Comment: And how exactly?

Comment: @Kimvais /boot/grub/grub.conf, when I trying to edit, it is showing, permission denied. so how exctly edit this, plz help ..

Comment: @IndianGirl I would try to edit the file like this on ubuntu/debian: `sudo vi /boot/grub/grub.conf`. Maybe your problem with editing is more complex than that, i don't know.

Comment: @Ben7005 now it is working (sudo vi /boot/grub/grub.conf). But I am very new to linux. so plz give me hint that how can I edit this ? means I have to set default=0 to default=1 . plz tell me

Comment: @IndianGirl I have given detailed instructions in my answer.

Comment: Even better, change the `default 0` line.

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks to Kimvais** for the location of the file, that was most of the answer!

To start, type in `sudo vi /boot/grub/grub.conf`.

This command works like this:

- `sudo` tells Centos that you want to perform the rest of the command with root privileges (so that you can save the file).
- `vi /boot/grub/grub.conf` tells Centos to use the vi program to edit `/boot/grub/grub.conf`.

Now that you are in vi, navigate (using arrow keys or h=left j=up k=down l=right) to the place that you want to edit and change the values that you want.

Now press `Ctrl+C`, then `:wq`, then hit `Enter`.

This works like so:

- `Ctrl+C` sets vi to command mode
- `:` begins the command
- `w` means save
- `q` means quit
- `Enter` runs the command, saving your file and then exiting vi.